# Plotting function defined via NIntegrate is too slow

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, parametric-functions

I have the following functions as solutions of a system of differential equations (for calculation, I used `ParametricNDSolveValue`)

```
lcgncrrsol[r_][t_] := sol[r][[1]]@t;
lcgncφφsol[r_][t_] := sol[r][[2]]@t;
lcgncφzsol[r_][t_] := sol[r][[3]]@t;
lcgnczzsol[r_][t_] := sol[r][[4]]@t;
```

Then for next calculation, I need to take these functions and integrate them from r = 0 to given r = r0.

```
NforceBint[t_?NumericQ] := 2*Pi*NIntegrate[nforceb[lcgnczzsol[r][t], lcgncφφsol[r][t], 
  lcgnczzsol[r][t]]*r*lcgnczzsol[r][t], {r, 0, r0}]
```

But when I want to plot the function `NforceBint[t]` (for example from t = 0 to t = 8), it takes extremely long (of the order of hours).
I assume the problem is that `NIntegrate` keeps recalculating during integration for different time values (and because of that there are so many calculations).

Any tips how to improve this and make the calculation significantly more efficient ("save" integral in the cache)?

EDIT: Definition of sol function:

```
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[
{
lcgncrr'[t] == -(lcgncrr[t] - primaryPathIndicator[t])*1/λ[t]*λ'[t], 
lcgncφφ'[t] == -1/λ[t]*λ'[t]*lcgncφφ[t] + (r/2*1/(λ[t])^2*Ψ[t]*λ'[t] + r*1/λ[t]*Ψ'[t])*lcgncφz[t] - primaryPathIndicator[t]*(-1/λ[t]*λ'[t]), 
lcgncφz'[t] == (r/4*1/(λ[t])^2*Ψ[t]*λ'[t] + r/2*1/λ[t]*Ψ'[t])*lcgncφφ[t] + 1/2*1/λ[t]*λ'[t]*lcgncφz[t] + (r/4*1/(λ[t])^2*Ψ[t]*λ'[t] + r/2*1/λ[t]*Ψ'[t])*lcgnczz[t] - primaryPathIndicator[t]*(r/2*1/(λ[t])^2*Ψ[t]*λ'[t] + r*1/λ[t]*Ψ'[t]), 
lcgnczz'[t] == (r/2*1/(λ[2/λ[t]*λ'[t]*lcgnczz[t] - primaryPathIndicator[t]*(2/λ[t]*λ'[t]), 
lcgncrr[tmin] == 1, lcgncφφ[tmin] == 1, lcgncφz[tmin] == 0, lcgnczz[tmin] == 1
}
, 
{lcgncrr, lcgncφφ, lcgncφz, lcgnczz}, {t, tmin,tmax}, {r}, MaxStepSize -> 1/10000, MaxSteps -> Infinity]
```

And definition of λ and Ψ functions (Ψ should be non-zero for other calculations):

```
λ[t_] := 1 + 1/2*t*(Cos[t])^2  
Ψ[t_] := 0
```

Comment: Can you include the definition of `sol`?

Comment: Try: `Evaluate@NforceBint...`

Comment: Use `NDSolve` instead of `NIntegrate`, which should give a huge improvement.

Comment: @ChrisK the definition of sol included. Thank you.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Please, can you show me how to use NDSolve in this situation? I´ve already tried that but without success.

Comment: The definition of `sol` contains errors, which first must be corrected.  Also, the definition is incomplete in that it contains the undefined quantity `primaryPathIndicator`.

Comment: A trick I often use when `Plot` is taking far too long because it is evaluating hundreds or even thousands of points. `ListPlot[Table[{t,NforceBint[t]},{t,0,8,1/2}],Joined->True]` and if 1/2 is too large then make it 1/4 or some other modest size value so that at most a few dozen points need to be evaluated to get an idea what the plot looks like.

Comment: The expression for `sol` contains syntax errors.  Also, `primaryPathIndicator` is undefined.